# Multiple index.html when using Angular UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm new to using Angular with Meteor. Currently I am struggling with using the Angular UI Router, where I have an `index.html` file which is like a main layout template with `<div ui-view></div>` where the router will render view templates in depending on the current route.

Is it possible to create more layout template files like `index.html`, and select which version of `index.html` we want to render a view template in?

This can be because most pages on the site uses a certain layout defined in `index.html`, but a few pages may require their own special layouts (ie: no header, etc)

Comment: Angular is meant to be a one-page-application so you dont need to do that. Here's a personal guide for whenever I'm starting a project. You cant create unique layout for each pages in this approach. See here. https://github.com/jofftiquez/angular-app-starter-pack

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use separate index.html pages, because that is where all the angular scripts are held, and transitioning to a new index.html means loading all your scripts again.

Instead, you can use [abstract parent states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views#abstract-states) which represent the template with their own `ui-view` for the child states to populate.

From the Ui-Router Wiki:

> ```
> $stateProvider
> .state('contacts', {
>     abstract: true,
>     templateUrl: 'contacts.html'
> })
> .state('contacts.list', {
>     // loaded into ui-view of parent's template
>     templateUrl: 'contacts.list.html'
> })
> .state('contacts.detail', {
>     // loaded into ui-view of parent's template
>     templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html'
> })
>
> <!-- contacts.html -->
> <h1>Contacts Page</h1>
> <div ui-view></div>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement to have many `index.html` files together with `ui-router` hits a weak design. But I will answer your question.

One way you can achieve different layouts in `index.html` is to have a `ui-view` manager directive which listens to the state. You can use this directive in all the different places your `ui-view` might go and get it to insert the directive `ui-view` depending on the state.

Also your directive can show/hide it's parent blocks to impose your layout configuration. This way you can configure your `index.html` layout blocks before `ui-router` replaces markup.